# Strange behavior of a macro in \LoadClass options

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

Consider the class file mwe.cls containing

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mwe}[2022/09/26]
\def\myGreatMacro{twoside=false}
\LoadClass[a4paper,\myGreatMacro]{scrreprt}%% warning about ununsed option
%\LoadClass[a4paper,twoside=false]{scrreprt}%% no warning
\endinput
```

and the input file mwe.tex containing

```
\documentclass{mwe}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Running `latex mwe.tex` spits out

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [twoside=false].
```

However, if we issue the option `twoside=false` to `\LoadClass` directly (rather than via a macro), the warning goes away.  Why? Which options are passed to scrreprt in each case in reality? How to pass a macro contents as an option to `\LoadClass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a special class. You can test that in a normal document:

```
\newcommand\myoption{twoside=true}
\documentclass[a4paper,\myoption]{scrreport}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
abc \newpage abc
\end{document}
```

gives a document which isn't in twoside.

KOMA processes key-values, and like most key-value handlers don't like if you hide the key-value in a command.

What does work it to put the whole option list in a command:

```
\newcommand\myoption{a5paper,twoside=true}
\documentclass[\myoption]{scrreport}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
abc \newpage abc
\end{document}
```